# Prevent duplicate code in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I'm using a lot of Rectangle controls in an UniformGrid. They are containing
all the same portion of XAML code which deals with setting the Fill property via MultiBinding (see example below). Is there a way to prevent this code duplication ? What would be the preferred way to accomplish a reduction of XAML code ?

Thx a lot !

```
<Rectangle>
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
            <Binding Path="Field"/>
            <Binding>
                <Binding.RelativeSource>
                    <RelativeSource Mode="Self"/>
                </Binding.RelativeSource>
            </Binding>
        </MultiBinding>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Comment: Create a new `UserControl`.

Comment: you can add templates for example in the app.xaml

Comment: You can write a style and add it to the application resource and reuse the style or you can create a custom control with same style and use it.

Comment: If you want to be able to reuse the style or templates in different projects you can put them in an library and get them using a resourcedictionary too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define a style:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <Style x:Key="RectangleStyle" TargetType="Rectangle">
      <Setter Property="Fill">
         <Setter.Value>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
               <Binding Path="Field"/>
               <Binding>
                  <Binding.RelativeSource>
                     <RelativeSource Mode="Self"/>
                  </Binding.RelativeSource>
               </Binding>
           </MultiBinding>
         </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
   </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And use it like this:

```
<Rectangle Style="{StaticResource RectangleStyle}"/>
```